# Mongodb: How to delete auto-generated _id from my fields?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Im using MongoDB and I have this issue that I cant solve. How do I remove the field "_id" that was auto-generated by the system from my MongoDB records. I can delete them one by one because I have 1000 of records and all of it has the _id. The picture below is what i have. I want to delete the _id (the first one)

[image]

But it is showing my this error.

[image]

Comment: you can't delete the _id, it ensure taht each document is unique and can be easily identified. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/ (_id field section) for details

Comment: then is there a way for me to hide it?

Comment: yes, with projection. for example, this will return the documents without _id field: db.contact.find({}, {_id: 0})